# How do I create a TEXT column?

Tags: 7, database

I am trying to create a TEXT column.

```
function _mymodule_installed_fields() {
  return array(
    'mymodule_summary' => array(
      'field_name' => 'mymodule_summary',
      'label' => $t('Summary'),
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'not_null' => TRUE,
      'length' => '400',
    );
  );
}
```

I get a VARCHAR column. How do I get a TEXT column?

Comment: Data type of 'text' is supported in Drupal in the [Drupal Schema API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!schema.inc/group/schemaapi) as well as other MySQL data types that are not part of the official Drupal data types. Refer the [Drupal Schema API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!schema.inc/group/schemaapi) documentation and to [hook_schema()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7) on how to set up the tables in your custom code. You did say where you code existed. The text data type is hardly ever used

Comment: I did refer to the Schema API, i used 'type'=>'text' as mentioned but it still come out as VARCHAR (255) after the table has been created. Any suggestion?

Comment: Is this D6 or D7? And Could you post the rest of your code and where this resides in your module because something doesn't make sense? 'field_name' Is not part of the Schema API.

Comment: this code is from mymodule.install file, i use drupal 7

Comment: One reason it isn't working is you are not using the proper code for Drupal 7. Refer to my two links on how to implement hook_schema() with the Schema API.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, i have updated the code above, please have a look and let me know. Thank you

Comment: Since the code is setting the *field_name* property, which is not used from `hook_schema()`, it is more probable it is defining an entity field.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code you are showing, which is similar to the code shown in [Fields API, create new content type](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2011-08-17/fields-api-create-new-content-type) I take you are adding a new field to a content type, not simply creating a new table field for a database table. This explains why the code is using properties like *field_name* or *label* that implementations of [hook_schema()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7.x) would not use.

The values you can use for the *type* property are the ones described from the [`hook_field_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_info/7.x) implementations. In particular, if you look at the code of [`text_field_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21modules%21text%21text.module/function/text_field_info/7.x), you will see the following descriptions.

- *text*: The field stores varchar text in the database
- *text_long*: The field stores long text in the database

The confirm of what database field type is used for each entity field type comes from the implementations of [`hook_field_schema()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_schema/7.x), in particular from [`text_field_schema()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21modules%21text%21text.install/function/text_field_schema/7.x).

```
case 'text':
  $columns = array(
    'value' => array(
      'type' => 'varchar',
      'length' => $field['settings']['max_length'],
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ),
  );
  break;
case 'text_long':
  $columns = array(
    'value' => array(
      'type' => 'text',
      'size' => 'big',
      'not null' => FALSE,
    ),
  );
  break;
```

So, if you effectively need to use a *TEXT* database column  type, you need to use the following definition for the field.

```
array(
  'mymodule_summary' => array(
    'field_name' => 'mymodule_summary',
    'label' => $t('Summary'),
    'type' => 'text_long',
  );
);
```